# Return a tuple of objects

Tags: python

In the `Person` object, there is already a support for an inventory, and when the `Person`
object takes a `Weapon` object or `Food` object, the object would go to the inventory. For
our `Tribute` object, we want a way for us to retrieve the `Weapon` and `Food` objects from
the inventory.
Create a new method in the `Tribute` class, `get weapons()`, which would return a
tuple of `Weapon` objects that the `Tribute` currently has in his inventory

```
class Tribute(Person):


    def get_weapon(self):
        for item in self.get_inventory():
            if isinstance(item, self.RangedWeapon):
                return tuple(item)
            else:
                pass

    cc = Tribute("Chee Chin", 100)
    chicken = Food("chicken", 5)
    aloe_vera = Medicine("aloe vera", 2, 5)
    bow = RangedWeapon("bow", 4, 10)
    sword = Weapon("sword", 2, 5)

    Base = Place("base")
    Base.add_object(cc)
    Base.add_object(chicken)
    Base.add_object(aloe_vera)
    Base.add_object(bow)
    Base.add_object(sword)

    cc.take(bow)                           # Chee Chin took bow
    cc.take(sword)                         # Chee Chin took sword
    cc.take(chicken)                       # Chee Chin took chicken
    cc.take(aloe_vera)                     # Chee Chin took aloe_vera



    def add_object(self, new_object):
        if isinstance(new_object, Thing) or isinstance(new_object, LivingThing):
            self.objects.append(new_object)
            new_object.place = self
        else:
            GAME_LOGGER.warning("You can only add Thing or LivingThing to {}".format(self.get_name()))

    def named_col(col):
        # Only accepts tuple/list
        type_col = type(col)
        if type_col != list and type_col != tuple:
            return None

        return type_col(map(lambda x: x.get_name() if isinstance(x, NamedObject) else x, col))
```

When I try to `print(named_col(cc.get_weapons()))`   I am getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'RangedWeapon' object has no attribute 'owner'


class Thing(MobileObject):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name, None)
        self.owner = None 

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.owner

    def is_owned(self):
        return self.owner is not None
```

RangedWeapon is previously define under this class `class RangedWeapon(Weapon):`

Comment: Will you please provide full traceback?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `if isinstance(item, RangedWeapon)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if isinstance(item, self.RangedWeapon):
    return tuple(item)
```

You aren't returning a tuple of all weapons, you're converting one weapon from a named tuple to a regular tuple and returning the single object. This strips the named attributes, hence the error. Instead, you need something like:

```
def get_weapon(self):
    weapons = []
    for item in self.get_inventory():
        if isinstance(item, RangedWeapon):
            weapons.append(item)
    return tuple(weapons)
```

You should also move all of the code outside `get_weapon` (`cc = Tribute("Chee Chin", 100)` onwards) outside the class entirely, i.e. dedent it all one more tab.

Comment: Sorry I am still getting 'RangedWeapon' object has no attribute 'owner' I have added in the Class Things above please read

Comment: Why not add the definition of `RangedWeapon`? Is `Weapon` a `Thing`?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def get_weapons(self):
   weapons = []
   for item in self.get_inventory():
     if isinstance(item, RangedWeapon):
        weapons.append(item)
     elif isinstance(item, Weapon):
        weapons.append(item)
   return tuple(weapons)
```