# How do i solve Attribute Error?

Tags: python

We need a way for our `Tribute` object to reduce their hunger. Create a method `eat(food)`, which takes in a `Food` object. It will reduce the hunger of the player by the `food.get food value()`. If object that's passed to the `eat` method is of the type `Medicine`, it will increment the player’s health by `medicine.get medicine value()`.

Pre-defined code:

```
class Tribute(Person):
    def reduce_hunger(self, hunger):
        self.hunger = self.hunger - hunger
        if self.hunger < 0:
            self.hunger = 0
        else:
            return self.hunger

class Thing(MobileObject):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name, None)
        self.owner = None 

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.owner

    def is_owned(self):
        return self.owner is not None

class Person(LivingThing):
   def take(self, thing):
    # Can only take things in current location and not owned by others
        if isinstance(thing, Thing) and thing in self.place.objects and not thing.is_owned():
            thing.set_owner(self)
            self.inventory.append(thing)
            self.place.del_object(thing)
            GAME_LOGGER.add_event("TOOK", self, thing)
        else:
            GAME_LOGGER.warning("{} cannot take {}.".format(self.get_name(), thing.get_name()))

def named_col(col):
    # Only accepts tuple/list
    type_col = type(col)
    if type_col != list and type_col != tuple:
        return None

    return type_col(map(lambda x: x.get_name() if isinstance(x, NamedObject) else x, col))

class Food(Thing):
    def __init__(self, name, food_value):
        self.name = name
        self.food_value = food_value
    def get_food_value(self):
        return self.food_value


class Medicine(Food):
    def __init__(self, name, food_value, medicine_value):
        super().__init__(name, food_value)
        self.medicine_value = medicine_value
    def get_medicine_value(self):
        return self.medicine_value

class MobileObject(NamedObject):
    def __init__(self, name, place):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.place = place

    def get_place(self):
        return self.place
```

This is my code:

```
def eat(self, food):
    if food in self.get_inventory():
        self.inventory.remove(food) # not self.inventory = self.inventory.remove(food) cos self.inventory is a list. if use = it wont return anything
        self.reduce_hunger(food.get_food_value())
        if isinstance(self, medicine):
            self.health = self.health + food.get_medicine_value()
            if self.health > 100:
                self.health = 100
            elif self.health <0:
                self.health = 0
```

To test my code:

```
cc = Tribute("Chee Chin", 100)
chicken = Food("chicken", 5)
cc.take(chicken)                        # Chee Chin took chicken
cc.take(aloe_vera)                      # Chee Chin took aloe vera
print(named_col(cc.get_inventory()))    # ['chicken', 'aloe vera']
```

i got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Food' object has no attribute 'owner'
```

instead of the expected output 'Chee Chin took chicken'.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Where is `Food` defined? What's the rest of your error message (including line numbers and stack trace)?

Comment: And, as an extension of Kevin's line of thinking: does `Food` interit from `Thing`?

Comment: Yes it is inherited from Thing

Comment: Perhaps you should collaborate with the OP who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955707/return-a-tuple-of-objects)

Comment: `.food`, not `.food_value` ?

Comment: Can you post the code for class `MobileObject`? Or the `import` statement, if you imported it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Food` is a subclass of `Thing` but `Food`'s `__init__` doesn't call `Thing`'s `__init__`. That is the source of the problem. `Food`'s `__init__` needs the following line at its start:

```
super().__init__(name)
```

Comment: Furthermore, now that the superclass `__init__()` is being called, the `self.name = name` line is no longer needed in `Food`.

Comment: You use `super()` when you need to initialize variables that exist in a parent class. "Okay, so how do I know when I need to do that?", you might ask. Easy! In every subclass you create. Basically, `super().__init__()` should be the first executable line in *any* subclass' `__init__()`. (Just pass in the variables that need to be sent to the parent. In this case, `name`.) I would suggest you bookmark [this post on Python inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) and refer to it periodically.